# How can I beat the final boss in Swordigo?

Tags: swordigo

I have been trying for hours to beat the final boss (in world's end keep) and beat the game. I can easily take out the flying boss by using dimension rift and getting him to walk around, but I just can't beat my clone. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the magic armour and mostly maxed all of your stats. Carry a potion with you and put the shadow trinket on your armour. The first boss you need to use dimension rift, if you manage to hit him when he it above you you can spam attack and he cant hurt you. For the final boss don't use magic bolts because he will almost always block them and reflect them back to you. make sure you have fire trinket on your sword. Jump over his head when he does his ground attack and run to the other side, keep doing this to slowly regain health with your shadow trinket. When you approach him try to get a few hits then run away. Continue to do this for a while and soon you will kill the boss.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I played that game but I remember that fight.

I used to get back in the left corner and wait for him to come by. If he got too close I attacked him and then stepped back to the left corner.

Also I don't remember how it's called but you have blue magic you can throw at him you can use that while he is out of reach and you are waiting for him to come closer.

Answer (score 2):

Keep jumping over him and attack from behind. Make sure you have the fire trinket on your sword; it makes the sword stronger.

Answer (score 1):

I just beat that last boss. Not sure if you still need help, but I just did jump attacks and ran away when I needed health back. I managed to beat him within 2-3 minutes quite easily and still had full health.

Mainly as long as you do jump attacks and spam the attack button, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to win the final boss is provided by the developers :P .
There is a glitch in the stage. Just go to the left most corner of the stage. The evil clone can not cross the last pillar. And there is enough space that you can stand without harm. So if you are adventurous, fight the clone and when you want to regenerate, just stand there in the left most corner. Or if you are lazy, Just go to the left most corner, start hitting him at correct time with sword or shoot magic at him.

Answer (score 0):

The Dragon part is a bit easy for me. When you defeat the Dragon go to the left corner and use the magic bolt to break the Ball Of Chaos then you will see your copy. Stay in the left corner as it cannot pass the last pillar. Use your Sword to hit it when he is not attacking. Hope it works though I didn't try it out.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was I just jumped over the master of chaos’ head and attacked him, then ran away and repeated this same process. However, I defeated him in his Bird/eagle/griffin form by hitting the blasts he threw at me right back at him, and that did A LOT of damage!

Answer (score 0):

Put fire trinket on your sword for extra damage
Put shadow trinket on your magic armor for regen
Select Dragon’s grasp as your magic attack ; it rarely gets blocked and ain’t deflected at you

When the dialogue is over you can jump towards him hit him mid-air and then 2 ground attacks
When he is doing ground attacks hit him from above
Don’t approach him with ground attacks, the bot is almost perfect in dealing with that
If you want some distance or healing time spam “jump and dragon’s grape”
If he is doing a jump attack, if you aren’t in his range jump after him with your own jump attack but if you are in his range jump back or dash past him whichever is faster, if you can follow it up with a ground attack or preferably a jump attack

If you can’t beat it, try using a health potion or using the glitch that involves sitting at the side of the map where the AI won’t be able to reach you and killing him via that.

Answer (score 0):

I killed him spam attacking and jumping back. Also, I brought a health potion as I knew this would be helpful.

Comment: Hello! This is a low quality answer since 1- You basically retold what was in another answer and 2- Its not very developed. How does that strategy make it easier? Have a nice day and we will see you around!